# How do I run test scripts from TestTrack Test Case Manager in Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, testtrack

I use Seapine's TestTrack Test Case Manager (TCM) under Linux and thus far have been unable to figure out how to use its ability to kick off our Perl test scripts and save the resulting data into a test run.  Could someone provide me with a config, or example?

Answer (score 1):

Sean,

Take a look at the Script Agent mechanism on our [Labs site](http://labs.seapine.com/TCMScriptAgent.php). That will allow you to kick-off the Perl scripts.

If you have any questions about that, or want some help shoot me an email (mharp@) and we can talk.

Comment: That page talks a lot about Win32, but not one bit about Linux, can you elaborate on how do this in Linux.